# How to set an array of Objects in useState using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

```
 const res = {
      results: {
        documents: [
          {
            suggestion: 'tes1',
          },
          {
            suggestion: 'test2',
          },
          {
            suggestion: 'test3',
          },
          {
            suggestion: 'test4',
          },
        ],
      },
      meta: {
        request_id: '0e6aa4da',
      },
    };
```

I would like to set that "res" data into useState().

So I created inferface:

```
interface IResult {
  documents: [
    {
      suggestion: string;
    }
  ];
}
```

This is how look like my useState:

```
  const [querySuggestionResult, setQuerySuggestionResult] = useState<IResult[]>(
    []
  );
```

I want to set this json file (response form API) into the useState, so i tried

```
setQuerySuggestionResult([{documents: res.results.documents}]);
```

I tried like that as well

```
setGuerySuggestionResult(res.results.documents);
```

[an error what ive got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEHWU.png)

Can someone explain to me how to set an array of Objects to useState please !!

Comment: It should just be `setQuerySuggestionResult(res.results.documents);`

Comment: just fix mistake sorry for that

Comment: I tried setGuerySuggestionResult(res.results.documents); but not working

Answer (score 6):

I find the easiest way to be using an `Array` generic type (`Array<T>`):

```js
interface Foo {
    id: string;
}

const [list, setList] = useState<Array<Foo>>([]);
```

You can also specify an array literal (`T[]`):

```js
const [listAlt, setListAlt] = useState<Foo[]>([]);
```

```js
// edit: another way using `readonly`
const [readonlyList, setReadonlyList] = useState<readonly Foo[]>([]);
const [otherReadonlyList, setOtherReadonlyList] = useState<ReadonlyArray<foo>>([]);
```

Note that to use `readonly`, using `Array<...>` will **not** work (i.e., `readonly Array<Foo>` will **not** work). You must use the `readonly Foo[]` notation **or** use `ReadonlyArray<Foo>`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the interface definition is incorrect? Should it not be something like this?:

```js
interface IResult {
  documents: {
      suggestion: string;
    }[];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did like that:

First updated interface:

```
type SuggestionType = { suggestion: string };
export interface IResult {
  documents: SuggestionType[];
}
```

Second updated useState:

```
const [querySuggestionResult, setQuerySuggestionResult] = useState<IResult>();
```

And at last I am able to setState like this:

```
setQuerySuggestionResult(res.result);
```

Thank You! Like it shere it !